# what is data type of {'Content-Type:':'text/plain'} in response.writeHead() method?

Tags: javascript, node.js

The common way to creating web server in node.js is something like this:
`response.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/plain'});`,but what is data type of `{'Content-Type:':'text/plain'}` section? an `Object`? or a `tuple`?
I have never seen anything like that before in Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an anonymous object. Have you seen something simple like this:

`{x: 10}`

Well it is the same thing except it has a '-' in the key name so the key has to be put in quotes. The object is using specific naming that corresponds with the standards for HTTP headers ([ref](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.5)).

Comment: Thank you @Cymen. I've seen something like your example, but I didn't think the key can be a `String`.

Comment: @SaeedNoori Ah, yeah, it can be a `String`. In fact, when you use `Object.keys`, you'll see they all come back as strings. Try using numbers as keys and you'll see some interesting things!

Comment: but if I be right, the key is a `variable name` and variable names can't contain qotes.

Comment: @SaeedNoori The key is not a variable name.

Comment: @SaeedNoori It is an interesting question though -- the keys are really properties. The MDN reference for Object.keys explains better than I can: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys -- does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Text/plain is full text like .txt file.

In text/plain content, the HTML doesn't be parsed.
If you write "`<b>Hi</b>`", you will see the same thing ("`<b>Hi</b>`").